# How to limit list by using HAVING in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to limit a result set to 5 from each merchant_id by using HAVING in MySQL 5.7. Unfortunatelly this does not seem to work and I can not figure out why.

My SQL query joins three tables together and identifies categories where the manufactuer has a listing in. I want to limit this list to 5 per merchant_id:

```
SELECT
    mcs.CAT_ID
FROM tbl1 mc
    INNER JOIN tbl2 mcs ON mc.ID = mcs.CAT_ID
    INNER JOIN tbl3 p ON mcs.ARTICLE_ID = p.SKU
WHERE
    p.MANUFACTURER_ID =18670
group by 
    mc.merchant_ID, mcs.CAT_ID
HAVING 
    COUNT(mc.merchant_id) < 5
```

I was reading on SO that having gets executed without looking at the where statement, but what would be the right way to limit this list?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "without looking at the where statement", but having applies to each result row individually, so count will be no different than if you had `COUNT(mc.merchant_id)` in your select list.

Comment: mysql 8 and mariadb have window functions that can consider more than one row for purposes like this; with 5.7 you will have to do one of the crude workarounds

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide tables schema and dummy data, so I can't be sure about the exact query, but I'd use the following approach:

```sql
SELECT
    mc.merchant_id, t.CAT_ID
FROM tbl1 mc
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT mcs.CAT_ID
    FROM tbl2 AS mcs
    WHERE mc.ID = mcs.CAT_ID
    AND EXISTS (
      SELECT 'x'
      FROM tbl3 AS p
      WHERE p.SKU = mcs.ARTICLE_ID
      AND p.MANUFACTURER_ID = 18670
    )
    LIMIT 5
  ) as t
;
```

With the subquery in the join I select all the CAT_IDs relate to that mc.ID which have the listing for the product selected (18670), limited to 5 rows. In this way the limit to 5 is applied to each merchant_id